# ReactJS - update component (generated from a list) in the same div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's a basic question but I searched for a guide without success...

I want to have a list of dropdowns and inputs and each dropdown will change the input next to it.

```
var list = [{ name: "foo1"}, {name: "foo2"}];


return (
    {list.map( (name) => {
        return (<div>
                    <dropdown data={someData} 
                        onChange={(ev) => {
                                       if(ev.value == 'clearIt') 
                                            <CHANGE THE NEAR INPUT VALUE>
                                     }
                             }/>
                     <input value={name.name} />
                </div>)
     })});
```

I don't want to use DOM nor ref cause I understood that it's better to avoid it.

Any suggestions?
Or maybe the ref is the only option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you can achieve this by doing the following steps:

- Create a new component and move the dropdown and input to this new component.
- Add state to your component by following this example:
  https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class
- Add an event listener onChange to the dropdown with an event handler which can update the state you created in the first step. (Remember to bind the handler in the constructor.
- Add the new component within the div element of this example you gave and pass the relevant data you need to the new component you created.

This should allow you to update only the input next to the dropdown. Also it allows you to have different data for each dropdown you created.

Comment: Indeed it's a good solution, thanks! although I prefer to avoid too many components, so I just wanted to know if the only option is to use ```ref``` or maybe there is another workaround...

Comment: If I understand correctly you only need to create one component and let the map render that component for you multiple times. So you would not need to create 4 component to render if that is what you are saying. Anyway I would probably use ref then since I don't know about a workaround.